# Bootstrap Icons will not change color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Icons inside nav-links in a Sidebar, using Bootstrap V5 and Bootstrap Icons.

I am declaring an icon like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white">
        <img class="text-white" src="/img/journal-text.svg" width="16" height="16"/>
        Sidebar Link
    </a>
</li>
```

The text itself does indeed render as white, but the icon itself remains black. This remains the case even if I explicitly style the image tag with `fill: #fff; color: #fff`, the icon remains black. Is there any way to style this without modifying the SVG itself?

Bootstrap docs show that applying a `text-white` class should be enough to style the icon:
https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#styling

Answer (score 0):

To use Bootstrap icons and allow styling to be applied to them just like normal text, you need to use them via the `<i>` tag: `<i class="bi-github" role="img" aria-label="GitHub"></i>`.  Otherwise, use a [CSS color filter](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) to change the color of your SVG.